# How to find "qp3_medias" folder on your device

Tags: android

I'm following a `guide` that asks to put file inside `'/internal_storage/qp3_medias'`. Where can I find this folder on my Samsung device?

Comment: What exactly is `qp3_medias`? Add some brief .

Comment: I assume, that's a folder name.

Comment: Yeah that's already understood from the question . My question is this related to `Android` or its a Device or APP Specific?